# How to save the content of TinyMCE using HTML in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, tinymce, save

Does anyone know how to save the content in the TinyMCE editor into flat files (.txt) using HTML & Javascript in Google Chrome?

The content in the TinyMCE editor is retrieved from a flat file called **hi.txt** and once it's edited, it needs to be saved back inside **hi.txt**.

I embedded the TinyMCE editor into a webpage and this webpage is hosted via Dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Browsers don't have access to the local filesystem. What you can do is submit the contents of the editor to your server, and have the server send you back the file as a new hi.txt as a download.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, I reread the question.
It's not possible with only HTML & Javascript.

So, no.